# How to count various hardware/software events in the system using linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls, kernel-module

While searching for the same I came across a system call perf_event_open() in linux, which can be used to find various events to get the system performance. At the end of this man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html there is an example for this.

Now I want to create a linux kernel module which can be used to find such event counts. We can't use perf_event_open() in kernel space, since in the code it's using copy_from_kernel() etc systemcalls http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/events/core.c#L7445.

Is there anyway to use that systemcall in kernel module or any other way to count such events in kernel module. I am using linux kernel 3.18.1.

Comment: if you are in kernel mode, why not looking at the implementation of perf_event_open() system call? It's defined in kernel/events/core.c

Comment: @tristan I have already looked into that and it very lengthy and lots of function calls are there. Writing full code again for kernel module won't be feasible.